# Get specific "<elm>..</elm>" with PHP regex?

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a variable (`$page`) that contains HTML code as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>head</head>
    <body>
        <strong>12</strong>
        recommendations 
        <br />
        <strong>50</strong>
        connections
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to get the number of connections (in this case it's `50`) with a regular expression in PHP, so I use this:

```
preg_match('#<strong>(.*)</strong>#', $page, $connections)
```

But this gets `12`, not `50`. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you want both values or always the 2nd one? Always the last one? Always the one before "connections"? (Also, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags - there are better/easier ways to handle HTML.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_match('/<strong>([0-9]*)<\/strong>\s+connections/', $page, $connections);

echo $connections[1]; // 50
```

Comment: +1 Because, if this must be an ugly regular expression - which I am opposed to, but that's another issue - it is best to make it specific to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

With the caveat that Regular Expressions should not be used to parse HTML, take a look at [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all). If the HTML follows that structure, you are interested in the second match.

Comment: should be `preg_match_all` - damn SO not allowing one char edits

Comment: @JasonMcCreary it works, but can I use #<strong>(.*)</strong>/\r\n/connections# ? in fact I want to add "connections" in Regex, how to do it?

Comment: Yes. Looks like **Craig Mason** has provided that answer.